# PHP Order by popularity

Tags: php, mysql, max

Basically i have a bit of a problem with a program I'm writing.

```
$like= "dale dale dale dale dale dale dale dale dale dale dale dale marris jvc marris        travis travis chris chris chris today is not a day for christmas";
```

Above is a string of words

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM advertising"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$bw =  $row['Keyword'];
echo $bw;
echo ": ";
echo substr_count($like,$bw);
echo "<br>";
```

basically i connect to a mysql database, and search for pre determined phrases, these phrases could be updated at any time so its necessary that they are in a sql DB.

What I'm trying to do is order these phrases and selecting the most popular, however, there could be 5 most populars. What i need to do is selecting randomly one of these most popular items.

Is there a best way to do this? I was thinking of loading the values into a SQL db and ordering by most popular?

Cheers

Travis

Comment: would it be possible for you to post the schema for the advertising table?  What columns are in there?  Name?  Some sort of popularity rating that gets incremented?

Comment: What is your definition of "most popular?" It's impossible to answer your question properly without knowing that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is in your select all your items by random in your initial query. That way, if there are 5 items tied for most popular in your DB, the 1st one that is found will be random.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM advertising ORDER BY RAND()";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * from (
      select keyword, count(*) ct, rand() as r
        from advertising
       group by keyword
       order by ct
       limit 5) topfive
 order by r
```